# Анимация увеличения, вращения SVG элемента

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть SVG с Inkscape. В этом наборе SVG с `viewBox` я хочу анимировать каждый элемент внутри SVG.
У меня нет проблем с `translate` или `opacity`,но когда мне нужно повернуть или масштабировать отдельный элемент, он ведет себя странно.
Я пытаюсь правильно понять концепцию `viewBox`, но мне необходима помощь.

Я понимаю, что у меня есть только одна `origin point`, когда у меня есть только один `viewBox`., Мне нужно применить   несколько окон просмотра для реализации трансформации нескольких фигур SVG?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="SVGRoot" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 
  
  <ellipse id="path9238" cx="332.91" cy="143.85" rx="64.941" ry="67.676" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000"/>
  
  <rect id="rect9240" x="400.59" y="270.31" width="173.63" height="177.73" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;paint-order:normal"/>
 
  <path id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;paint-order:normal"/>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55425245/7394871

Answer (score 4):

В SVG координаты любой фигуры всегда имеют абсолютное значение, которое рассчитывается  от верхнего левого угла холста SVG.
Поэтому при применении команды `scale(2)` координаты центра фигуры увеличиваются тоже в два раза и фигура сместится влево и вниз.

```html
<svg id="SVGRoot" version="1.1"  width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid grey;">
     <rect  id="rect9240" transform="scale(2)" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100"   style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;> stroke:#000; paint-order:normal">
 
 <animateTransform
     xlink:href="#rect9240"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="scale"
  values="1;2;2;1;1"
  dur="8s"
  fill="freeze"
  repeatcount="indefinite"
  />
 </rect>  
      <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="3" fill="black" />
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="3" fill="dodgerblue" />
  <text x="150" y="140" font-size="16px" text-anchor="middle" > Center (150,150) </text>
   <text x="300" y="290" font-size="16px" text-anchor="middle" > Center (300,300) </text>
</svg>
```

Для возвращения увеличенной фигуры на исходное положение необходимо применить команду `translate(X, Y)`

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902773/7394871) есть прекрасный пост `@Paul LeBeau` где подробно объяснено это.

### CSS решение

Чтобы не рассчитывать положение центра фигуры, можно воспользоваться правилом CSS `transform-box: fill-box;`

При выбранном значении атрибута  `fill-box`

> The object bounding box is used as the reference box.

Другими словами, - ограничительная рамка вокруг объекта используется как контейнер, внутри которого будут происходить трансформации. 
И чтобы найти центр контейнера и тем самым точку вращения, устанавливаем -
`transform-origin:50% 50%;`

- *Ниже пример увеличения и уменьшения фигур SVG*

```css
svg {
width:50%;
}
.ellipse1, .rect1, .path1 {
transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: scale 3s linear infinite alternate;
 animation-direction: alternate;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
}


@keyframes scale {
    0% { transform: scale(0.5); }
    100% {  transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVGRoot"  version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <ellipse class="ellipse1" id="path9238" cx="332.91" cy="143.85" rx="64.941" ry="67.676" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000"/>
  
  <rect class="rect1" id="rect9240" x="400.59" y="270.31" width="173.63" height="177.73" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00; stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
  
  <path  class="path1" id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 </svg>
```

- Пример вращения

```css
svg {
width:50%;
}
.ellipse1, .rect1, .path1 {
transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite alternate;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% {  transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

```html
  <path  class="path1" id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
</svg>
<svg id="SVGRoot" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <ellipse class="ellipse1" id="path9238" cx="332.91" cy="143.85" rx="64.941" ry="67.676" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000"/>

  <rect class="rect1" id="rect9240" x="400.59" y="270.31" width="173.63" height="177.73" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00; stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>

  <path  class="path1" id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
</svg>
```

- Увеличение и вращение

```css
svg {
width:50%;
}
.ellipse1, .rect1, .path1 {
transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: scale1 4s linear, spin 4s linear 4s infinite alternate;
 transform-origin:50% 50%;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes scale1 {
    0% { transform: scale(0.5);}
    100% {  transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVGRoot" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   
  <ellipse class="ellipse1" id="path9238" cx="332.91" cy="143.85" rx="64.941" ry="67.676" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000"/>
  
  <rect class="rect1" id="rect9240" x="400.59" y="270.31" width="173.63" height="177.73" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00; stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
  <path  class="path1" id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
</svg>
<svg id="SVGRoot" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   
  <ellipse class="ellipse1" id="path9238" cx="332.91" cy="143.85" rx="64.941" ry="67.676" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000"/>
  
  <rect class="rect1" id="rect9240" x="400.59" y="270.31" width="173.63" height="177.73" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00; stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
  <path  class="path1" id="path9242" d="m233.79 453.52-153.64-138.25 196.55-63.937z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#f00;stroke:#000; paint-order:normal"/>
 
</svg>
```